# How to solve duplicate static IP between network adapter in VB?

Tags: vb.net, wmi

I have a program so user can switch and apply network configuration based on profile.

```
Public Shared Sub SetIP(ByVal nicName As String, ByVal IpAddresses As String, ByVal SubnetMask As String, ByVal gateway As String, ByVal dnsSearch1 As String, ByVal dnsSearch2 As String)

    Dim objMC As ManagementClass = New ManagementClass("Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration")
    Dim objMOC As ManagementObjectCollection = objMC.GetInstances()

    'Dim objMO As ManagementObject
    For Each objMO As ManagementObject In objMOC
        'Make sure this is enabled device. Not VMWare or memory card
        If objMO("IPEnabled") Then


            If (objMO("Caption").Equals(nicName)) Then

                Dim objNewIP As ManagementBaseObject = objMO.GetMethodParameters("EnableStatic")
                Dim objNewGate As ManagementBaseObject = objMO.GetMethodParameters("SetGateways")
                Dim objNewDns As ManagementBaseObject = objMO.GetMethodParameters("SetDNSServerSearchOrder")

                'Set DefaultGateway
                objNewGate("DefaultIPGateway") = New String() {gateway}
                objNewGate("GatewayCostMetric") = New Integer() {1}

                'Set IPAddress and Subnet Mask
                objNewIP("IPAddress") = IpAddresses.Split(","c)     'major changes
                objNewIP("SubnetMask") = New String() {SubnetMask}


                'Set DNS for only preferred
                'objNewDns("DNSServerSearchOrder") = dnsSearch1.Split(","c)
                'Dim setDns = objMO.InvokeMethod("SetDNSServerSearchOrder", objNewDns, Nothing) 'comment jap


                'try to set alternate here
                Dim dns() As String = {dnsSearch1, dnsSearch2}
                objNewDns("DNSServerSearchOrder") = dns


                Dim setIP = objMO.InvokeMethod("EnableStatic", objNewIP, Nothing)
                Dim setGateways = objMO.InvokeMethod("SetGateways", objNewGate, Nothing)
                objMO.InvokeMethod("SetDNSServerSearchOrder", objNewDns, Nothing)


                Exit For

            End If
        End If

    Next

End Sub
```

By using WMI classes, right now WIFI adapter already set with 172.25.35.12 static IP address, and user want to switch to Ethernet which also will be using the same IP address.

After set with that IP, it will cause conflict where WIFI adapter is disabled. How can I solve the issues? Maybe I need to reset WIFI IP configuration at first..

Comment: Why would you have two network interfaces with the same IP Address?

Comment: Static ip is given by my company. So that can connect company network. Want to use ethernet instead of wifi @Jimi

Comment: Well, if you set a static IP Address in one Interface, set the other to use DHCP instead.

Comment: If you enable DHCP instead of, e.g., disabling the Interface, you better release the Lease and then renew it.

Comment: why? can you explain. Thanks @Jimi

Comment: In case you're using the same server / router to access the Network both via Ethernet and WiFi and the DHCP range overlaps with ranges assigned / assignable to static IP Addresses. So you don't reproduce the same conflict you're trying to avoid now. If the Ethernet and WiFi connections use different hardware, which is used to connect to a specific Network with limited Addresses, you probably cannot avoid a conflict of assignment, so you have to disable one of the Interfaces when you change medium.

Comment: Unless, as mentioned, the DHCP is configured to provide addresses in a range that is distinct from the ranges assignable to static IP Addresses, then you might have a choice. It depends on the Network configuration and the purpose of these connections (something only you know about).